# access to HTTP server object in node.js express

Tags: node.js, express

I am inside a middleware (`function(req, res, next) {...}`).

Is there a way to access the HTTP server object from the `req`?

UPDATE

Let me be more specific.  I am trying to find out a port that the server listens on, or unix socket path, if it's listening on that.

Comment: There is.  If you do a `console.log(req)`, one of the properties references the server.  It isn't documented and may change in the future, but it's there.  I don't know the name of the property as I don't have Node handy, sorry.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about in your main app file:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();

app.use(app.router);

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.socket.server);
});

app.server = http.createServer(app);
app.server.listen(3000);
```

As Brad mentioned, Express does expose something resembling the object returned from `#createServer()`, however, TJ has been giving serious consideration to dropping any inclusion of the HTTP module in express in future releases. Using the code above will be future safe.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't work, since `req.app` is not defined: http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params. Please have a look at my answer

Comment: Tested and it does work. Also has the added benefit of allowing you to separate out your routes/middleware from your main file which your answer doesn't allow.

Comment: Just saw Brad's comment; you are right, it will work. But it is undocumented.

Comment: Or `var httpServer = http.createServer(); httpServer.on('request', app);`

Answer (score 8):

If what you are trying to do is expose the server object inside your routers, then yeah, middleware is the way to go:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(function(req, res, next){ //This must be set before app.router
   req.server = server;
   next();
});

app.use(app.router); 

server.listen(3000);
```

The middleware is used to expose the server object. Then, you can just access it in any of your routers like so:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.server.get('port')); // displays 3000
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Function `app.listen` returns your http server.

**Source** `express/lib/application.js`

```
app.listen = function listen() {
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

Comment: Now that you mentioned it, I also spotted it in the docs: _The `app.listen()` method returns an `http.Server` object …_ http://expressjs.com/de/4x/api.html#app.listen

Answer (score 4):

for some reason, for me `request.app.server` did not work, probably because I was using express 4, after bit of digging up, I found that `req.socket.server` works.