# How do I get the http.server from the express app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am writing a server-side node.js application that uses express to handle HTTP requests and I'm adding websockets (socket.io) support. However I don't have access to the code that starts the HTTP server. I am writing an express router and functions to handle various URLs. My code looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.post( myURL, myFunction );
```

When setting up the router I want to use socket.io to listen for websocket connections as well. I cannot pass `express` or `express()` into `require('socket.io')( xxx )`, I need to pass the http.Server object. But since I didn't start the server, how can I get it?

Comment: try accessing the server from req inside myFunction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548921/access-to-http-server-object-in-node-js-express

Comment: Where is your code that starts the server?  The code you've shown doesn't start a server at all.  There should a `xxx.listen()` somewhere in your code. As far as I know, you can't get the server object from the Express `app` object.  It doesn't know the server.  But your code that does `xxx.listen()` will know the server so you need to get it from there.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

As far as I know, the Express `app` object does not know the server object.  The way things work in Express, the `app` object is given to the server object, not the other way around.  In fact a single `app` object can even be used with more than one server (sometimes done for an http and https server).

You can get access to the server object from within a request handler with `req.connection.server`, but that comes from the server as part of the context with a request, that's not something the `app` object itself knows.

So, if you want access to the server object for use with socket.io at initialization time, you will have to capture the server object into a variable where it is created.

The code you show in your question does not create or start a server.  The usual two ways to start a server for use with Express are this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
// Express creates a server for you and starts it
const server = app.listen(80);
```

Or, you create the server yourself and pass express to it as the handler:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
// you explicitly create the http server
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
server.listen(80);
```

In each of these cases, you end up with the server object in a variable and can then use that with socket.io.

---

You can get access to the server from inside an Express route handler within the processing of a request from either the `req` or `res` object that are passed to a request handler.

```
res.connection.server
req.connection.server
```

Comment: Yes, this is my point. The code to start the server is somewhere else, all my code does is add a router. I don't have access to the code that calls `listen()` or calls `createServer`, so I was hoping there was a way to get it from express or somewhere else. The answer linked to in the first comment helps.

Comment: @GraemePerrow - Well, you can get the server from either the req or res object while in the middle of processing a request, but that is not what you asked.

Answer (score 15):

The server is returned when you call `app.listen()`.  For example:

```
const server = app.listen(process.env.NODE_PORT, () => {
  console.log('Listening', server.address());
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can write a simple wrapper to either instantiate or get the Socket IO instance in your Express app, by putting the following in some file:

```
//Dependencies
const socketIo = require('socket.io');

//Placeholder for instance
let io;

//Export handler to instantiate or get instance
module.exports = function(server) {
  if (server) {
    io = socketIo(server);
  }
  return io;
};
```

Then, you can instantiate this instance the usual way when setting up Express:

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('./path-to-your-file')(server);
```

And when you need it later in your routes or code elsewhere, you can get it as follows:

```
const io = require('./path-to-your-file')();
```

This is of course a simplified example, but you can modify the logic to suit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem when I used wepack devServer with socket-io and jfriend00's comment helped me. I use this trick:

```
let server;
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (!server){
        server = req.connection.server;
        //do fancy staffs with http-server
    }
    next();
})
```

Comment: Oh my god! This was the only thing that worked for me while writing tests using mocha and chai! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following code to accomplish the same thing.

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(80);
```

For more information, I sugges that you refer to [this link](http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4)

Comment: How can i do https? i have the same syntax you used but var server = require('https').Server(app); doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: First of all, as many suggestions on web forums and facto practices, encrypt conmmunications via HTTPS from Node built-in tools is not a good idea to take it to production because security flaws. Instead use a proxy option like NGINX. You can get more about it on many posts.

Answer (score 1):

have a look on how express `listen` function is implemented:

```
app.listen = function listen() {
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

So basically it does not matter if you store http server instance explicitly:

```
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
```

Or refer to returned value of express `listen`:

```
var server = app.listen()
```

You technically referring for same thing, which is somehow confusing IMHO... Maybe it would be better to explicitly expect developer to pass express app as http server constructor parameter, because `app.listen()` basically works as a wrapper around `http.Server(arguments)`